# Deserialize nested JSON array in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json-deserialization, javascriptserializer

I have a JSON array with nested objects, representing a menu, as this:

```
[
    [
      {
       "name": "Item 1",
       "id": 1
      },
      {
       "name": "Item 2",
       "id": 2,
       "children": [
        [
         {
          "name": "Item 21",
          "id": 21
         }
        ]
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "Item 3",
       "id": 3,
       "children": [
        [
         {
          "name": "Item 31",
          "id": 31,
          "children": [
           [
            {
             "name": "Item 311",
             "id": 311
            },
            {
             "name": "Item 312",
             "id": 312
            }
           ]
          ]
         },
         {
          "name": "Item 32",
          "id": 32
         },
...
```

And I want to deserialize it using JavaScriptSerializer. I have some code as shown below but is not working.

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var objects = serializer.Deserialize<Menu>(jsonData); 
...


public class Menu
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Menu[] children { get; set; }
    }
```

The error I get is "The type 'Menu' is not supported to deserialize a matrix".
I would appreciate any help on how to declare the custom object.

Cheers.

Comment: The menu is an html list that is then serialized as a JSON array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your root object is a 2d [jagged array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) of objects.  The properties `"children"` are also 2d jagged arrays.  Thus your `Menu` class needs to be:

```
public class Menu
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Menu [][] children { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialize your JSON as follows:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var objects = serializer.Deserialize<Menu [][]>(jsonData);
```

Alternatively, if you prefer lists to arrays, do:

```
public class Menu
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<List<Menu>> children { get; set; }
}
```

And then

```
var objects = serializer.Deserialize<List<List<Menu>>>(jsonData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could the issue be that the actual data is an array but you're telling it to expect just one Menu?