# Good way to parse this dynamic JSON

Tags: c#, arrays, json, dynamic

I have JSON data that varies based on account settings.  It has a "values" array that can contain zero or more arrays of field values and a columnNames array that gives the column name that goes with the values.  Here is an example:

```
{
  "values": [
    [
      "32999000000001",
      "32999*****0001",
      "Joe",
      "Doe",
      "joe@doe.com",
      "1/1/1900",
      null,
      "1234",
      null,
      "222-111-2223",
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      "UNITED STATES",
      null,
      null,
      "Acme, Inc."
    ],
    [
      "39999000000002",
      "39999*****0002",
      "Joe",
      "Schmoe",
      "joe@yahoo.com",
      "1/1/1990",
      null,
      "333-555-4444",
      null,
      "123 Some Street",
      null,
      "Michigan",
      null,
      null,
      "UNITED STATES",
      null,
      null,
      "Acme, Inc."
    ],
  ],
  "columnNames": [
    "accountNumber",
    "Acct Number",
    "First Name",
    "Last Name",
    "Email Address",
    "Date Of Hire",
    "Anniversary Date",
    "Phone Number",
    "Other Phone Number",
    "Address1",
    "Address2",
    "City",
    "State",
    "Postal Code",
    "Country",
    "Company",
    "Club ID",
    "Member Type"
  ]
}
```

I need to populate an array of business objects with this data (the business object has a property for each column name in the JSON data that I am interested in):

```
public class SearchResultRecord
{
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfHire { get; set; }
    public DateTime? AnniversaryDate { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string OtherPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string ClubId { get; set; }
    public string MemberType { get; set; }
}
```

I am planning to use JSON.NET for this and I could create a custom attribute to decorate each property and then use reflection to do the mapping of the values to the right property, but I am hoping that there is an easier / cleaner way or perhaps something already built into JSON.NET that I can use.

**What is a clean, good way to accomplish this?**

Note that I do not *have* to use JSON.NET if there is a more suitable library out there.

Comment: Seems like the easiest would be to transform the incoming JSON, so that the arrays of arrays become arrays of correctly keyed objects. Then parse it as per usual.

Comment: extra comma in there `"Acme, Inc."
    ],]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code will do the transformation for you:

```
var props = typeof(SearchResultRecord).GetProperties().ToDictionary(
                    x => x.Name, 
                    StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var data = (Dictionary<string,object>)jss.DeserializeObject(json); 
var cols = ((object[])data["columnNames"]).OfType<string>()
                                          .Select((x,index) => new{index,name=x.Replace(" ","")})
                                          .Where (x => props.ContainsKey(x.name))
                                          .Select (x => new {x.index,prop=props[x.name]}).Dump();
var rows = ((object[])data["values"]).OfType<object[]>().ToArray();

foreach (var row in rows)
{
    var rowdict = cols.Where (c => row[c.index] != null).ToDictionary(c => c.prop.Name, c => row[c.index]);
    var rowjson = jss.Serialize(rowdict);
    jss.Deserialize<SearchResultRecord>(rowjson).Dump();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that your JSON data structure should be as this:

```
{ "values": [ [...], [...], ...], "columnNames": [...] }
```

Thus, you have to create list that wraps SearchResultRecord:

```
public class SearchResultRecord
{
     // other entities here
     ...

     // nested list used to hold jagged array values
     public List<List<SearchResultRecord>> values { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize the jagged array to pre-defined generic list using JavaScriptSerializer:

[Deserialize nested JSON array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36658590/deserialize-nested-json-array-in-c-sharp)

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

SearchResultRecord model = new SearchResultRecord();
var result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<List<SearchResultRecord>>>(jsonData);
model.values = result;
```

I recommend you to separate the column name declarations (single array) from its values (jagged array) in de-serialization process, since they have different array size and structure.

Comment: You're right, @Mark. The correct form is [[...], [...], ...] (some group of arrays inside a single array)