# Create nested for loops when the number of iterations are unknown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have json that is similar to this:

```
{
  Name: Level 1,
  Children: [
    {
       Name: Level 2,
       Children: [
        {
           Name: Level 3,
           Children: [
             {
                Name: Level 4,
                Children: [
                  {
                     Name: Level 5,
                     Children: []
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Currently the depth level is five, and I'm trying to use nested for loops similar to this:

```
for()
{
   for()
   {
       for()
       {
            for().....
```

But I'd like to know if I there is a way to generate this without using so many for loops, because currently the depth level is five but could be more.

Comment: "I'd like to know if I there is a way to generate this..." What are you trying to generate?

Comment: Why not using a JSON deserializer such like `JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize` to shorten process? Find out similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36658590/deserialize-nested-json-array-in-c-sharp.

Comment: For such scenarios you can use recursive methods instead for loops

Comment: I need to create a tree like structure without any plugin, serialized or not I'd still need to so many for loops, which  I'd like avoid.

Comment: If you need all the information from the deeper (inner) levels you surely *have* to iterate them in any way. Of course you may hide that away from your API-users by some linq, but that won´t change anything on the number of iterations. So what exactly are you asking?

Comment: I got the answer, using Recursive method type. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider that, at some later point you have decided to add few more levels. With this looping approach, you need to modify the code, add more nested loops to deal with that scenario. So we can say that this won't  be a good approach For this specific case, I suggest you use a recursive method like the following:

```
public void RecursiveMethod(object inputCollection)
{
   // process here
   if(Check for child collection)
   {
       RecursiveMethod(inputCollection.Children)
   }
   // process here no more child exists
}
```

** Note:** Make use of appropriate type instead for `object` in the above code, since it is a JSON you can use one serializing approach to get the collection, but still you need the recursive method to process the collection outed from the serializer

Answer (score 2):

**Json Model:**

```
class JSONModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public JSONModel Children { get; set; }
}
```

**Recursive Method:**

```
public static JSONModel GenerateJSON(int depth,int i=0 )
{
        var jsonModel = new JSONModel();
        if (i < depth)
        {
            jsonModel.Name = "Level " + (++i);
            jsonModel.Children = GenerateJSON( depth, i);
        }
        return jsonModel;
 }
```

Call Recursive Method by passing dynamic depth value e.g. var `jsonModel = GenerateJSON(5)`